# How to hide the parent div if all its child div are hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having dynamic created div's like this..

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>

<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>

<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

I am using this script to filter results...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search").on("keyup", function()
  {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".child").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
    });
  });
});
```

This is working perfectly, what I want to achieve is that suppose the search value does not match in any of child of first div, then it should hide the parent div as well i.e. first div.

Comment: How come you are using a `filter` without returning anything and it is working fine?

Answer (score 3):

Loop trough the parents and check whether all children are hidden:

```
$('.parent').show();
$('.parent').each(function() {
  if (!$(this).find('.child:visible').length) {
    $(this).hide();
  } else {
    $(this).show();
  }
})
```

Comment: Its working file but when i am changing the value in #search the parent div which just got hidden are hidden only... how to show them back

Comment: Yes, correct. I completed the above code with the else clause, thanks.

Comment: I corrected again, thanks. It seems that it did not loop through the hidden parents. So it is mandatory to make all of them visible before looping them.

Comment: Your code worked.. but it has slowed down my page... the search option while typing is lagging while using your code.. please help me to optimize it

Comment: You need to use `debounce` for the input. Please find the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51837825/how-to-debounce-input-with-jquery-and-lodash

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").on("keyup", function()
    {
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $(".child").filter(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
      });
      //here is the code to hide
      $(".parent").each(function() {
        if($(this).find('.child:visible').length===0)
            $(this).hide();
        else 
            $(this).show();
        });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Its working file but when i am changing the value in  #search the parent div which just got hidden are hidden only... how to show them back

Comment: in else part just show it again., updating the code.

Answer (score 0):

This one is similar to above except for the fact that you can use `toggle_visibility()` else where as well

```
function toggle_visibility() {
    if (!$(this).find('.child:visible').length) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
    else {
        $(this).show();
   }
}

$('.parent').each(toggle_visibility)
```