# How to debounce input with jquery and lodash

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

If you are trying to hide and show children based on an input's value with jQuery it will cause performance issue while typing. To avoid calling the filter function after every character, use the `debounce` method of `lodash`.

**html**

```
<input id="search" />

<div>
  <div class="child">foo</div>
  <div class="child">bar</div>
  ....
</div>
```

**javasrcript**

```
  var filterChildren = function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".child").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
    });    
  };

  $("#search").on("keyup", _.debounce(filterChildren, 300));
```

Do not miss to import [Lodash](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js) and [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js).

PS: this is part of the answer of the this post:
[How to hide the parent div if all its child div are hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51835751/how-to-hide-the-parent-div-if-all-its-child-div-are-hidden/51835982?noredirect=1#comment90626492_51835982)

Answer (score 0):

I propose another solution without lodash. Just create a map on page load with your elements (assuming they do not change and are created only once on page load).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var map = {};
  $('.child').each(function(i,el){
    map[$(el).text().toLowerCase()] = $(el);
  });
  $('.child').toggle(false);
  $('#search').on('keyup', function(){
    $('.child').toggle(false);
    var el = map[$(this).val().toLowerCase()];
    if (el)
      $(el).toggle(true);
  });
});
```

[Live preview](https://codepen.io/theofanis/full/qywoxM)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#search").on("keyup", _.debounce(filterChildren, 300));

function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
    var timeout;
    return function debounced() {
        if ( timeout ) {
            clearTimeout( timeout );
        }
        function delayed() {
            fn();
            timeout = null;
        }
        timeout = setTimeout( delayed, threshold || 100 );
    };
}
```